# Can't seem to get inside geolocation html5 API in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am fairly new to android programming.
Am trying to fetch my current location and show the coordinates on an html page.
I know there are a lot of answers to the same problem but no matter what I do I neither the success or the error functions of geolocation API will get executed.
If anyone of you can take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong that would be a great help.
Am not sure if it's the issue but get

```
           disableGcForExternalAlloc== false in the logcat.
```

Have tried rebooting the device ,clearing the cache but all in vain

Here's my code

main activity

```
    package com.sys.demomap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
    import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WebView view;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeoLocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });
    view.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mymaps.html");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

javascript in the webview

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var watchID;
    function showLoc(position){
       alert("latitude :::::::::::"+position.coords.latitude);
       alert("longitude"+position.coords.longitude); 
    }

    function errorHandler(){
      alert("not working");
    }

    function getLocation()
    {
       console.log("into getlocation::::::::::::::::::::");

       if (navigator.geolocation)
       {
           alert(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition);
           var options={maximumAge:600000, timeout:100000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLoc,errorHandler,options);

       }

    }


</script>
```